# Blocking VPN connections to my server

Tags: linux, vpn

I have a server in one game (it's called Mindustry). On average, 60 people constantly play on the server, about 10,000 unique users enter per day. Some people (they are using VPNs) bypass all the bans and interfere with regular players. I need an easy and free way to block all VPN connections to my server.

Some info:

- the server is running on a dedicated host with Ubuntu 20.04
- i have a root access on the host
- this game (Mindustry) supports loading java mods & plugins, they can track the connection of a player and get his ip
- the game code is here: https://github.com/anuken/mindustry

I tried using public free anti-vpn APIs, but i need at least 10000 queries per day, however no API gives you that much. I also tried to set up the firewall on my host, but idk where can i find all VPN IPs and how do i block them all.

Comment: https://vpnapi.io/pricing - 19$ for 10k queries. $29 for 50k. In addition you should probably implement a caching strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Good, Fast, Cheap, pick two.

I have restricted access in the past by introducing additional layers such as adding a VPN or a portal that would effectively whitelist the user/ip.

One thought that immediately comes to mind is generating a whitelist based on a sister application. For example, if you have a discord server, you can get user IPs to create a whitelist that could be automatically updated. You could also create a basic web site and distribute links (Sms, Email, Discord, Etc) containing tokens to do the same thing.